# What are these UNKNOWN addresses in resource monitors network tab?

Tags: windows

wmpnetwk.exe , system and svchost seemed to have an "UNKNOWN" Address by them. It stopped after a minute or so, but what was it it? I can upload an image, but if I dont need to is that okay?

Wmpnetwk.exe had a pid of 3640
Svchost.exe had a pid of 1840
System had a pid of 4

Is this normal for resource monitor to show an unknown addresss? It showed unknown under system, svchost and wmpnetwk.exe. they were receiving a couple 100-1000 bytes a second, for around 30 seconds. Note my brothers win 7 laptop was also active on the network. Is this okay or is it bad?

Comment: WMPnetwk.exe is part of Windows Media Players sharing. Svchost is an executable wrapper for windows service .dll's. What was happaning at the time that makes you think there is a problem

Comment: I understand they are legitimate programs.  There was nothing in particular that happened, but I was alarmed the address was unknown. In event viewer under security, there is a log saying there was an anonymous log off at around the same time I saw it.